# How to use Azure DevOps to track tasks done yesterday and task to be performed today?

Tags: tools, daily-scrum, devops

How can i configure Azure DevOps to get reports similar to daily scrum meeting template. There is need to get report on what task was worked on yesterday, and what task will be done today, effectively generating the day wise report for the work done.

Is there any provision in Azure DevOps to do this or can we configure DevOps to get such report?

Answer (score 0):

We are still optimizing our use of Azure Devops, so there may be a better way to do this that we have not discovered yet. I will share what is working for us right now.

In order to create this type of report using Boards|Queries, we configured additional fields for Product Backlog Items, Tasks, Test Cases, etc. This is done in the *Organizational Settings*, for the *Process* that you are using, for the *Work Item Types* that you want to update.

This will provide access to additional fields to be manually edited for tracking. So far we have used the built-in fields such as *Start Date*, *Finish Date*, and others.

We prefer to not have manual fields to support reporting, but if the fields are thoughtfully added to forms it is not too difficult for the team to update them.

If we are missing some built-in features that would provide a simpler approach to your question, I am eager to hear them!

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured sprints in ADO to align with your sprint cadence? You could assign committed work to the current sprint and enter your team's sprint goal, setup a taskboard with a burndown or burnup chart to use during your daily standups. Then, walk the board at your daily to review items that are in progress first, and have the team surface any concerns about successfully achieving the sprint goal immediately to the scrum master. Some of the teams who I have worked with also filter their work by the owner field. You could write queries to identify tasks that are planned to be started that day (and ones that were already in progress) but that would require the entire team to update the data in a consistent manual way, I believe.